# How to fetch the selected row in a bindingsource

Tags: bindingsource

How to fetch the selected row in a bindingsource.
I thought this was the solution:

```
       DataRow row = ((DataRowView)bindingSource1.Current).Row;
```

But I still get the whole datagridview
If I stand on 'row' open the tree while I'm running my application I can select the Itemarray and see the selected data. but dont know how the change this line

```
       DataRow row = ((DataRowView)bindingSource1.Current).Row;
```

Could somebody help me solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

```
object row = ((DataRowView)bindingSource1.Current).Row[i];
```

`i` is the column index

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I solved it like this
           object[] obj = ((DataRowView)bindingSource1.Current).Row.ItemArray;